# how te send a line to a function in bash?

Tags: bash

i wrote this function in bash and it is not giving me anything when i test it just print an empty line , so i think my problem is in the way i actually run the function , and how to give it a line. 
--> the function accepts a line in format of words and between each word one space now the line ends with a word that contains 5 letters for example :

> "dog cat something 777A "

or it will end with a number between 0-100 after the word with  letters for example :

> "dog cat something 777A 88"

now the function accepts the line and should print the number that is beween 0-100 but if the number doesn't exist the function should print "-" instead.

this is the function

```
function get { 
  local num_words=`echo "$1" | wc -w`      
  let num_words--
  echo "$1" | while read -a line ; do
  while (( num_words > 0 )) ; do
   number_letters=`echo ${line[$num_words]} | wc -c`
   let number_letters--
   if (( number_letters < 4 )) ; then
   echo "${line[$num_words]}"
   break
   fi
   echo -
   break
   let num_words--
 done
 break
 done
}
```

and this is how i tested it :

```
 line="444444 wefd sfdggag 987f 98"
result="`echo "$line" | get`"
echo $result
```

and i get an empty line when i run the function.

Comment: This might be because of the IFS (internal field separator).. do IFS=$'\n' one line before result=... and see if that fixes it..

Comment: personally I think you should change the code to use $@ and loop through that.. and also it's bad practice to use while in a pipe as it messes around with scoping of variables..

Comment: thank you ! i am gonna stop doing that , also i fixed the code with help of  Olivier Pellier-Cuit  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you test it. You should write:

```
#!/bin/sh
function get { 
  local num_words=`echo "$1" | wc -w`      
  let num_words--
  echo "$1" | while read -a line ; do
  while (( num_words > 0 )) ; do
   number_letters=`echo ${line[$num_words]} | wc -c`
   let number_letters--
   if (( number_letters < 4 )) ; then
   echo "${line[$num_words]}"
   break
   fi
   echo -
   break
   let num_words--
 done
 break
 done
}

line="444444 wefd sfdggag 987f 98"
#result="`echo "$line" | get`"
result="`get "$line"`"
echo $result
line="cat cats dog 1217A"
result="`get "$line"`"
echo $result
```

Comment: i did this too but still the same problem : result="`get  "$line"`"

Comment: i have tested it and i get the output 98. Which shell are you using ?

Comment: "SSH Secure Shell "

Comment: could you give me the result of echo "$SHELL"

Comment: when i use bash i write these two lines also :  setenv SHELL /bin/bash

Comment: exec /bin/bash --login

Comment: i get this when i type echo"$SHELL" --> "/bin/bash"

Comment: Could you try to do an exact copy/past of my edited response and try it ?

Comment: if it's still not working try to replace #!/bin/bash with #!/bin/sh

Comment: no the problem is on your computer. bash is bugged in your case :)

Comment: it works perfectly but the only problem now that if i test the function with line like this one : "cat cats dog 1217A" it prints 1317A instead of -

Comment: Really ? in my case it's print "-". Which os is running on your computer ?

Comment: Try to do again an exact copy of the code in my response and give me the result

Comment: microsoft windows 7 ultimate

Comment: --> x64 based pc

Comment: i just put #!/bin/sh at the begining and add your example

Comment: this is weird ! beacause when i do echo $0 i get bash

Comment: also when i did echo "$SHELL" i got bin/bash !! do you know why this happednd ? :/ also THNK YOU SO SO MUCH

Comment: #!/bin/sh at the begining of the script use sh only during the execution of your script. it's not change your global shell

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, arguments can be retrieved from $1, $2, etc. When calling the function, they should follow its name:

```
my_func () {
    echo "Argument 1: $1"
    echo "Argument 2: $2"
}
my_func arg1 arg2
```

When you want the function to process standard input, don't use arguments. Pipe it to the function instead. Inside the fucntion, just process the input - either read it by `read`, or filter it by `grep`, or whatever.

```
my_func () {
    let i=1
    while read line ; do
        echo $((i++)) "$line"
    done
}
ls | my_func
```

Comment: also i used this function in a script the way yo u told me but everything prints exept for the result !! could it be that the problem is actually from my computer ? or bash is not working properly on my computer !?